# How can I get vim youcompleteme plugin to properly list function names?

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, centos, vim-plugin

I have installed *ycm* and newest *vim* in my *centos7* using the following command:

`cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe./install.py --clang-completer`.

When I type something like:

```
std::vector<int> a;
a.
```

I want it to list vector's functions such as `std::vector::push_back` and `std::vector::pop_back` as options for code completion, buy it's showing other things.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure is your problem the same as mine or not.

I guess there is not `vector` in your namespace `std` for YCM, you can try typing `std::` and look for vector, if fail, it means YCM didn't include `<vector>` successfully. And then move `#include<vector>` to the top of file before all of other includes, you can finally use use `std::vector` in YCM.

If so, it was what occur to me no long ago.

And I try

```
install.sh --clangd-completer.
```

After that YCM can work for STL.

What YCM suggest is:
[image]

Now I have changed to `clang-completer` back by reinstalling YCM cause `clangd` didn't work so excellent, and now `clang-completer` works successfully.

I don't know what wrong happened while I installed YCM, just hope it can help you temporary to use YCM now.